# Shell Backupscript messed up directories

Tags: wordpress, shell, backup

I try to backup a wordpress site with a script like this:

`tar -czPf $BACKUP_DIR/$FILE -C $WWW_DIR .`

But it keeps messing up the directories. In my root directory is a folder "contact-form-7" with directory structure "includes/js/jquery-ui/themes/smoothness/images/" it contains images. This folder should be in my root /wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7..." not in my root directory.

why is this happen? is there an operation in tar for that?

```
NOW=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H%M")
BACKUP_NAME="cleanWordpress"
FILE="$BACKUP_NAME.$NOW.tar.gz"
BACKUP_DIR="/home/user/www/backups"
WWW_DIR="/home/user/www/clean.wordpress.ch"
DB_USER="user"
DB_PASS="pw"
DB_HOST="host"
DB_NAME="db"
DB_FILE="$BACKUP_NAME.$NOW.sql"
tar -czPf $BACKUP_DIR/$FILE -C $WWW_DIR .
mysqldump -h$DB_HOST -u$DB_USER -p$DB_PASS $DB_NAME > $BACKUP_DIR/$DB_FILE
```

Comment: What is the value of $WWW_DIR ?

Comment: You must have other code in there, because a tar does nothing but read a directory structure (or files, but in your case you specify `.`) and create the tar file.  It will never move "contact-form-7" from `/wp-content/plugins` to `/`.

Comment: i added the code in my question

Comment: is there maybe another Script I can us? Still not working.

Comment: zip -9r $BACKUP_DIR/$FILE $WWW_DIR works for me but don't know why it is not working with tar